# Apache2 All catalogs without index.html or php are forbidden

Tags: server, permissions, apache2

All catalogs that havent index.html, or .php are forbidden. I can't access it by server (for example I can't use css in folder css).
My apache2.conf

```
<Directory />
        #Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found how to solve it. On catalog var/www I changed owner to my-username:www-data on all files. After that I added every permission to group. Works fine.